# How to get a slice from "arguments"

Tags: javascript

All you know that `arguments` is a special object that holds all the arguments passed to the function.

And as long as it is not an array - you cannot use something like `arguments.slice(1)`.

So the question - how to slice everything but first element from `arguments`?

**UPD**:

seems like there is no way without converting it to an array with

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

If someone posts another solution it would be great, if not - I'll check the first one with the line above as an answer.

Comment: +zerkms there is indeed a better way than taking `arguments` and converting it to an array etc. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Meddling with array functions is not actually necessary.**

Using [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `...rest` is cleaner and more convenient.

**Example**

```js
function argumentTest(first, ...rest) {
  console.log("First arg:" + first);

  // loop through the rest of the parameters
  for (let arg of rest) {
    console.log("- " + arg);
  }
}

// call your function with any number of arguments
argumentTest("first arg", "#2", "more arguments", "this is not an argument but a contradiction");
```

**...Rest**

- See the [example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umurkaragoz/wkdm0ynw)
- See [MDN Documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Comment: Yep, I agree these days it's more convenient. I upvoted you but I won't retrospectively change the checked 5 years old answer.

Comment: Now after another year I think it's about time to switch to the new ES standards :-)

Comment: that feeling when you get +15 points for a one year old answer :-D

Comment: This won’t work with older Qt releases that don’t support this feature yet ☹

Answer (score 140):

**Q. How to slice everything but first element from `arguments`?**

The following will return an array containing all arguments except the first:

```
var slicedArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

You don't have to convert `arguments` to an array first, do it all in one step.

Comment: I believe there is a downside with this. If there is only one additional argument (besides the first one) nothing is returned.

Comment: @Trevor - No, it returns an array with one element that is the second argument. (Why would it return nothing?)

Comment: Yep, my bad. A different bug of mine was causing this.

Comment: Recommendation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) states that you should not use slice on arguments because it prevents JavaScript engine optimizations.

Comment: a more in detail explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)

Comment: ^ doesn't explain anything and simply states it leaks.

Comment: Seems that recommendation not to use slice on arguments is no longer there. The "more in detail" link does not seem to have any more relevant details. Seems like this is definitely the correct answer now.

Comment: @David - The "in detail" link still says not to use `.slice()` on `arguments`, but the only reason given is that it prevents JS engine optimisation of the function. So it's not that it fails, it just *might* be slower. I'm not going to write code to cater to optimisation in the JS engine of the day, not when the engine of tomorrow might have solved the optimisation problem, and in any case the difference probably won't be perceptible to the user in most cases. Better to write clear and easy-to-maintain code first, then come back and optimise only if a measurable performance issue arises.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I meant that it does not give any extra information other than "it leaks" - no explanation how or why. It seems like it would be okay to me, the only proviso is that it might not get optimised... I'm with you though, I'd not worry about that, and it seems like MDN agrees, having removed the advice not to do it.

Answer (score 13):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments:

> You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in
>   JavaScript engines (V8 for example). Instead, try constructing a new
>   array by iterating through the arguments object.

So Paul Rosiana's answer above is correct

Comment: Maybe so. But I don't see how optimization engines couldn't treat the accepted answer's one-liner and optimize it in any way they wish. It's always a nuisance in the long run if we start to code for the optimizers (of the day) - personally I prefer clarity of code.

Comment: 'slice' does not alter. It returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array. Elements of the original array are copied into the returned array. So I cannot understand what is difference between manual copy to new array and slice.

Comment: As of 2018, the warning is not there anymore. We should be safe, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

This can be a way:

```
var args = Array.from(arguments).slice(1);
```

Comment: These days it's not necessary at all: `function foo(...args)`

Comment: @zerkms I was about to dismiss your suggestion for performance reasons, but my test is showing rest parameters as the fastest solution! https://gist.github.com/18d590d12aef1e90d2ed262f4fab0c96

Comment: @CodyAllanTaylor implementations improve. Unless you have a really-really-really important reason to not to, I would stick to the more readable syntax

Answer (score 11):

You can "slice without slicing" by procedurally walking the arguments object:

```
function fun() {
  var args = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  return args;
}

fun(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); //=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Yeah, it does the work but makes no sense in case we have a `.slice()` ;-)

Comment: Of course it's easier to use `Array.prototype.slice`, but your question was if there was another way.

Comment: yeah, thanks for that ;-) (though obviously I know about `for` :-P )

Comment: Haha, I hope I didn't sound trite. Sometimes it's useful information on SO!

Comment: +1 This appears to be the only correct solution for V8. Take a look at the optimization benchmarking here: http://jsperf.com/leaky-args

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `[].slice.call(arguments, 1)`

[].slice will return you the slice function object and you can call it as the `arguments` and `1` are the parameters

Comment: Any change you checked through the posted answers before posting yours? The identical (and even slightly better, since it does not allocate a throw-away array) answer is already posted and is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ...rest within the function to separate the first and the rest of the arguments:

```js
function foo(arr) {
  const [first, ...rest] = arguments;
  console.log(`first = ${first}`);
  console.log(`rest = ${rest}`);
}
//Then calling the function with 3 arguments:
foo(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Yay, the future is here, finally :-D

Answer (score 0):

you can use this too

```js
function arg(myArr) {
  let arg = Object.values(arguments).slice(2, 4);
  console.log(arg);
  return arg;
};

arg([1, 2, 3], 4, [5,6], 7)
```

see here for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

...

Answer (score 0):

`Arguments` type is iterable, so using the `ES6 (ES2015)` spread `...` operator, then use `Array.slice([start], [end])` method, such as

```
function omitFirstAndLastArgument(value) {
  const args = arguments.length > 2 ? [...arguments].slice(1, -1) : [];
  return args;
}

omitFirstAndLastArgument(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); //  [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: One note though: `...` is _not_ an operator.