# underscore delay from scratch

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, delay

I'm studying underscore delay to better my JS skills, and I'm trying to explain every line to myself to make sure I understand. Could someone explain what this line is doing?

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

Is it taking the first 2 values of the arguments array and making it equal to var 'args'?

also,

shouldn't "wait" be a numerical value like 3000 milliseconds? wondering why it's spelled out?

```
_.delay = function(func, wait) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        func.apply(this, args);
    }, wait);
};
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2)` is extracting elements starting from 2 (index)

Comment: @Satpal Better state that `arguments` is not `array`.

Comment: This is fourth question row, I would recommend you to go through official dos first [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: The `arguments` object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: `wait` is spelled out because it's a parameter you'd pass to `_.delay()`: `_.delay(function(){/*DoStuff*/}, 1000)`

Comment: See also [How to get a slice from “arguments”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9510094/1048572) or [How can I convert the “arguments” object to an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/960866/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi: Dupe doesn't answer the (trivial) second half of the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus: People asking multiple questions in a single post never stopped me from closing it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);` is extracting (returning) all elements from the array starting at the second index. Try this in the browser console:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
// Output: [3, 4, 5]
```

Regarding `wait`: since `wait` is one of the passed parameters, it is spelled out. The content of `wait` should be an integer (in milliseconds), since that's what `setTimeout(callback, timeInMilliseconds)` is expecting as second parameter.

Comment: So, what is it, milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: `milliseconds` (sorry, had a typo)

Answer (score 1):

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

This line takes all but the first 2 parameters that are passed to `_delay`, to pass those on to the `setTimeout`.

`wait` is spelled out because it's a parameter you'd pass to `_.delay()`:

```
_.delay(function(){
    // Do stuff
}, 1000)`;
```

This parameter is then also passed on to the `setTimeout`

Basically, that implementation of `_.delay` does *exactly* the same as `setTimeout` does, with the disadvantage that it doesn't return an timeout identifier you could use to [clear the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout).