# Can I call a function inside another function without using the function's name?

Tags: javascript

```
function man(){

 function add(a,b){
     return a+b;
 }

 function sub(a,b){
     return a-b;
 }

 function pow(a){
     return a**a;
 }
}

man('pow',2);
```

Is there any way that I can call the power function using the call "man('pow',2)"..???

Answer (score 2):

No. This is one of the key ways to hide information/implementation in JS – [inside a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/1848578). There isn't any way to access a value that isn't exposed to the outside.

Perhaps you're looking for an *object*:

```js
var man = {

 add(a,b) {
     return a+b;
 },

 sub(a,b) {
     return a-b;
 },

 pow(a) {
     return a**a;
 }
};

console.log(man.pow(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

If your functions would be in global scope, than just do

```
window[functionName](a, b);
```

But since they are in your private scope I suggest adding them to some array and than call it:

```
function man(func, arg1, arg2) {
    var functions = {
        add: function (a, b){
            return a+b;
        },
        sub: function(a, b){
            return a-b;
        },
        pow: function (a){
            return Math.pow(a, a);
        }
    };

    functions[func](arg1, arg2);
}
```

---

Note that `**` works only in [ES7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Exponentiation_assignment)

Comment: How about environments where we don't have window object - e.g NodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

If you store each function mapped to a key, you could then invoke the function by its key:

```js
function man() {
  var funcs = {
    add: function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    },
    sub: function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    },
    pow: function(a) {
      return a ** a;
    }
  };
  return funcs[arguments[0]].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

console.log('pow of 2 = ' + man('pow', 2));
console.log('add 2 and 6 = ' + man('add', 2, 6));
console.log('sub 2 from 8 = ' + man('sub', 8, 2));
```

[`apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316389/4297364) allows you convert the arguments (which is **like** an array) into the equivalent of a bunch of parameters.

[`Array.prototype.slice.call`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510206/4297364) allows you to convert the arguments into an **actual** array so that you can skip the first one (which was used to identify the function to call).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object as reference to the functions.

```js
function man() {
    function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
    function sub(a, b) { return a - b; }
    function pow(a) { return a ** a; }

    return { add, sub, pow }[arguments[0]](...[].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

console.log(man('pow', 2));
console.log(man('add', 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, not a good idea to use eval. But, this will work

```
function man(funName, a, b){

 function add(a,b){
     return a+b;
 }

 function sub(a,b){
     return a-b;
 }

 function pow(a){
     return a**a;
 }

 return (eval(funName))(a, b)
}

man('pow',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in order to implement what you need here.

Comment: And how to use these Closures in this situation?