# forEach() vs Array.prototype.forEach.call()

Tags: javascript

I was just goin through the Electron API Demo code samples when suddenly a wild expression - which is completely foreign to me - appeared:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function (link) {
    // WWIII here
})
```

I definitely understand what this piece of code is doing but I am used to a syntax like this:

```
links.forEach(function (links) {});
```

So what exactly is the difference between those two? I have already read various StackOverflow threads about this topic but they are either ambiguous or don't answer the question at all. Some said it had something todo with array-like collections not being iteratable by .forEach() as opposed to Array.prototype.forEach.call(). Is that the only advantage of the overly tedious and long version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Advantage" isn't the right word here. `link` is not an array, it doesn't have a `links.forEach` property. So, in order to use `forEach` on that value, you have to get a reference to `Array.prototype.forEach` somehow.

Comment: `[].forEach.call(links, link => ...)` will work too.

Comment: @FelixKling Actually NodeList.prototype.forEach is the thing in major browsers. So we no longer need call hack to iterate with forEach interface.

Comment: @dfsq: Ah, that's good news :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Answer (score 38, accepted):

"class methods" in JavaScript [are actually functions defined on a `prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). That means that even if an object does not inherit from [the `Array` prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), you can call `Array` methods on it, as long as it follows the array structure (i.e.: It is an object with a `length` property and properties indexed by integers). However, the object holds no reference to `Array.prototype`, so you need to explicitly select `Array.prototype` as the object the method lives in.

The [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is neither an `Array` nor inherits from the `Array` prototype. However, as a `NodeList` has a similar internal structure to an `Array`, you can still use the `forEach` function. But since `NodeList` does not inherit from the `Array` prototype, trying to use `.forEach` on a `NodeList` would raise an error (this is not *exactly* true - see the note at the end of my answer). For this reason, you need to explicitly state that you are calling a method from `Array.prototype` on the `NodeList`, and that is done by using [the `.call` method from `Function.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

In summary:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link) { /* something */ })
```

means:

Take the `forEach` function from `Array.prototype` and call it on `links`, which is a non-`Array` object, with some function as its argument.

Note that on recent versions of browsers, the `NodeList` prototype *does* provide [a `forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Methods) which works the same as the `Array` one, so the example from the Electron API is probably using the `Array` version for compatibility with older versions. If you have a web app and only care about supporting modern versions of Chrome and Firefox, you can just call `forEach` on your `NodeList`. In fact, since [Electron updates about 2 weeks after whenever Chrome updates](https://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/), it should be safe to use `NodeList.prototype.forEach` in Electron. :)

Comment: "trying to use .forEach on a NodeList would raise an error" - actually no, because NodeList does provide forEach.

Comment: @georg But only on recent versions of browsers. On older versions, it would fail. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this is one beast of an explanation :)

Comment: Why does this not work: `templates = document.getElementsByClassName("tem")
 templates.forEach(function (template, ind,obj) {
 for (var schluessel in werte) {
 template.innerHTML = template.innerHTML.replace('','')}`? I get `Uncaught TypeError: templates.forEach is not a function`. I got it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). I want to do variable replacement in html and use the classes to reduce the dom crawling. `Array.prototype.forEach.call(templates, function (template)` does the job.

Comment: Best part for me was "as long as it follows the array structure (i.e.: It is an object with a length property and properties indexed by integers)". Clear condition for object to be array-like object so that I can call any Array methods by `Array.prototype.XXX.call`.

Answer (score 4):

This is interesting question. Half a year ago I would say that `link.forEach` is not about shorter syntax, but it is actually not supposed to work. Then I would explain what it means that many of array methods deliberately *generic*, which means that their internal implementation only considers numeric indexes and length property of the `this` object, but doesn't care about it being Array instance. Basically what @Pedro Castilho said in his answer.

However, now I will say that these days evergreen browsers (except IE11, Edge, as of April 2017) already implemented [NodeList.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) convenience method so you no longer need to use `.call` hack or `Array.from` in order to just iterate NodeList with `forEach`.

So my summary: if you don't need to support IE, then use `NodeList.prototype.forEach` rather than `Array.prototype.forEach`. It might be the same internally, but cleaner conceptually. If you do need to support IE and you don't want to include one more pollyfill then use `Array.prototype.call` or better `Array.from`.

Comment: This is arguably a minor bug in the Electron sample app since the code runs in 'browser' that is guaranteed to have this function. There's no need for the hack and it's just confusing.

Comment: Oh, if we know that we are in safe environment like Electron, then of course it's preferable to just use `links.forEach`. It's just not everyone knows about that yet..

Answer (score 3):

This may be related to how the `document.querySelectorAll` returns [a static `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) rather than [an `Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600343/why-does-document-queryselectorall-return-a-staticnodelist-rather-than-a-real-ar).

Using the `Array`'s prototype, you may still call the `forEach`, it is similar to [operating on arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510094/how-to-get-a-slice-from-arguments).